# Using google PubSub and GCP function, are functions ran in series or parallel?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using pub/sub to send some data to a cloud function for processing.  I am wondering if I send off a 100 messages, will that invoke 100 (or some max number) of cloud functions, or will it wait until its processed the first message, then take the next message off the top?  I know the order can not be promised, which is fine in this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages are not guaranteed to be processed in order, and they might be processed by multiple invocations of the function running in parallel on different virtual server instances.  Cloud Functions generally seeks to handle events as fast as possible by [scaling up server instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances) like this, up to [1000 instances per function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#additional_quotas_for_background_functions).  Your code must be able to handle this correctly.

Comment: The scale up of function is progressive. You won't instantiate 100 instance in the same time. According with the processing time, you will instantiate 10 or 30, maybe 50 instances. By the way, some will be processed in parallel, other in series.